# PHP/MySQL syntax to insert into multiple tables (many-to-many structure)

Tags: php, mysql, insert, bulkinsert

I am trying to insert data from one form into multiple MySQL tables (using MYSQL syntax, although I will be migrating the application MYSQLi at some point - this probably isn't relevant right now, but thought I'd say it to stop the "*you should be doing this in MYSQLi*" comments that inevitably follow - I know I should, and I will be... soon... but for a number of reasons out of my control, I can't yet, and we still need this working).

Essentially, I am inserting into a "many-to-many" table structure (i.e. instances that can be part of many categories, and categories that can include many instances). The main table `Instances`, has all of the main pieces of data (in this case, places on a map - for example 'Acme Cafe', 'Lakeside Picnic Area', etc); another table `Categories` includes all of the possible categories for all of the places in the `instances` table - for example, 'Cafe', 'Pub', 'View Point', etc; and a joining table `Instance_Categories`, connects the places in the `Instances` table to the categories in the `Categories` table.

The PHP form has the following fields:

- `Reference` (a 9 digit randomly generated identifier used to identify the instance with it's many categories in the `Instance_Categories` table)
- `Name` (text box)
- `Address` (text box)
- `Phone` (text box)
- `Tick-box` fields for each of the categories (8 of them).

The `Instances` table has the following columns

- `ID` (unique for the table)
- `Reference` (see form input above)
- `Name`
- `Address`
- `Phone`

The `Categories` table has the following columns

- `ID` (unique to the table)
- `Category` (varchar)
- `Category_Ref` (a number to identify the reference in the connecting `Instances_Categories` table)

The `Instances_Categories` table has the following columns:

- `ID` (unique to the table)
- `Instance_Ref` (from the form input above)
- `Category_Ref` (relating to the `Categories` table above)

How do I formulate the `INSERT` statement in order to insert the data into my database? Can I just formulate an insert command for each table and run them one after the other from the same "Submit" button? And how would I get the insert command to dynamically insert more rows into the `Instances_Categories` table depending on how many category tick-boxes have been selected? I'm tearing my hair out!

Comment: You create one insert for each. You'll need to use `mysql_insert_id` to get the values for the FK. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to insert to multiple tables with one query you can't.

You could use a transaction, but just run the multiple queries and call it a day.

Comment: I had a horrible feeling that it couldn't be done. What is 'running a transaction' in PHP (sorry, I come from a aspx.net world...). Can I just formulate an insert command for each table and run them one after the other from the same "Submit" button? And how would I get the insert command to dynamically insert more rows into the Instances_Categories table depending on how many category tick-boxes have been selected?

Comment: Sorry, meant procedure not transaction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075279/using-mysql-to-do-multiple-insert-on-linked-tables