# How to insert multiple mysql queries using node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to build an app where an user can registry/login and save his favorites movies.
Here's the database

[image]

This is my first project using MySQL and i found it hard at first to insert/get data for authentification but i managed to do it.

Now i'm trying to have a form where the user can insert movies, but i'm not sure how to do it, since i think i need to have multiple insert queries for : movies directors, user_movies...

What i tried :

```
app.post("/add", (req, res) => {

const userId = req.body.userId;
const title = req.body.title;
const year = req.body.year;
const image_url = req.body.image_url;
const runtime = req.body.runtime;
const rating = req.body.rating;
const director = req.body.director;
const genre = req.body.genre;
const description = req.body.description;

    db.query('insert into movies (title, year,image_url,runtime, rating, description)values(?, ?,?,?,?,?)',
        [title, year, image_url, runtime, rating, description], (err, result) => {
            console.log(err);
            res.send(result);
        }
    )
    db.query('insert into directors (name) values(?)',
        [director], (err, result) => {
            console.log(err);
            res.send(result);
    });
    db.query('insert into genres (name) values(?)',
        [genre], (err, result) => {
            console.log(err);
            res.send(result);
    });
});
```

})

Comment: You could use a stored procedure, see [Using Mysql to do multiple INSERT on linked tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075279/using-mysql-to-do-multiple-insert-on-linked-tables). Advantage is that you will have all SQL-stuff in 1 place.

Comment: Thank you, @Luuk! That is what i need! Post it so i can accept it as the solution.

Comment: You better give you votes to the person who answered the qeustion I was directing you to.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Luuk provides a good approach to solving this with the use of Stored Procedures. That can be helpful and efficient particularly when you need a newly created value from `insert_1` to be used in `insert_2` for example.

In your question you appear to already have all of the data your queries require.

If you would like to accomplish this entirely within your `Node` app and not use a stored procedure, [you can do so by enabling the `multipleStatements` config option](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#multiple-statement-queries).

An example is included below based on your sample code. In the first line of the `connection` config you will see where the `multipleStatements: true` is defined.

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createPool({
  multipleStatements: true, // required for multiple statements
  connectionLimit: 10,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST || '127.0.0.1',
  user: process.env.DB_USER || 'local_user',
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || 'local_password',
  database: process.env.DB_NAME || 'local_database',
  charset: 'utf8mb4' // necessary if you might need support for emoji characters
});

const db = connection;

app.post("/add", (req, res) => {
  let userId = req.body.userId;
  let title = req.body.title;
  let year = req.body.year;
  let image_url = req.body.image_url;
  let runtime = req.body.runtime;
  let rating = req.body.rating;
  let director = req.body.director;
  let genre = req.body.genre;
  let description = req.body.description;

  let query_1 = `INSERT INTO movies (title, year, image_url, runtime, rating, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?); `;
  let query_2 = `INSERT INTO directors (name) VALUES (?); `;
  let query_3 = `INSERT INTO genres (name) VALUES (?);`;

  db.query(
    query_1 + query_2 + query_3, 
    [title, year, image_url, runtime, rating, description, director, genre], 
    (err, results, fields) => {
      if (error) throw error;
      // results is an array with one element for every statement in the query:
      console.log(results[0]); // query_1 results
      console.log(results[1]); // query_2 results
      console.log(results[2]); // query_3 results
      res.send({all_result: results});
    });
  }
);
```

Be aware that support for multiple statements comes with increased security risks such as SQL injection attacks. Always be diligent to ensure values are properly escaped.

Comment: Thank you, this is even better !