# Optimising MySQL LEFT JOIN query for simple three table schema?

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization

I've written a job request system in PHP with a MySQL database and I'm having an issue with a slow query.

My schema (simplified) is as follows:

**tbl_job**
job_id
job_desc
requester_user_id

**tbl_user**
user_id
user_name

**tbl_workermap**
workermap_id
job_id
worker_user_id

A table containing the jobs, a user table for the possible workers and one to map workers to jobs. A job can have one or more workers, a worker can have one or more jobs.

tbl_user contains both users who request work, and those that work on the jobs, so user IDs are stored under worker_user_id in tbl_workermap and requester_user_id in tbl_job

When a job is logged it creates an entry in tbl_job but nothing in tbl_workermap until someone specifically assigns a worker. This means that when I query the jobs I do it with a left join as there are not entries in tbl_workermap for every job:

```
SELECT 
job.job_id,
job.job_desc,
workermap.worker_user_id,
worker.worker_name

FROM tbl_job AS job

LEFT JOIN tbl_workermap AS workermap
ON job.job_id = workermap.job_id

LEFT JOIN tbl_user AS worker
ON workermap.worker_user_id = worker.user_id
```

The system has been in use for a while and I now have about 8000 entries in tbl_job and 7000 in tbl_workermap and it's taking over 4 seconds to retrieve all results. An EXPLAIN query shows the tbl_workermap join returning around 7000 rows and "Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)".

Is there anything I can do to speed this up?

**EDIT: add table info**
I'd simplified things to explain but here's the actual table structure. There are more joins but tbl_workermap is the only problematic one:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_job` (
  `job_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `job_title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `job_description` text,
  `job_added_datetime` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `job_due_datetime` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `job_time_estimate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `job_additional_fields` text,
  `addedby_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `requester_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `worker_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `job_active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `site_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `estimategroup_id` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `brand_id` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `job_isproject` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`job_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `job_title` (`job_title`,`job_description`,`job_additional_fields`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8285 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1



CREATE TABLE `tbl_user` (
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_shortname` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_password` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_password_reset_uuid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_description` text,
  `user_sortorder` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_isworker` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `site_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_avatar_file_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_avatar_hub_url` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=917 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `tbl_workermap` (
  `workermap_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `job_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `workermap_datetime_added` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `workermap_datetime_removed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `worker_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `addedby_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `removedby_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `site_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `workermap_isassigned` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `workermap_active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`workermap_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7145 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

SHOW INDEX

```
+---------+---+-----------+---+-----------------------+------+------+------+------+-----+----------+--+--+
| tbl_job | 0 |  PRIMARY  | 1 |        job_id         |  A   | 8283 | NULL | NULL |     |  BTREE   |  |  |
+---------+---+-----------+---+-----------------------+------+------+------+------+-----+----------+--+--+
| tbl_job | 1 | job_title | 1 | job_title             | NULL |    1 | NULL | NULL | YES | FULLTEXT |  |  |
| tbl_job | 1 | job_title | 2 | job_description       | NULL |    1 | NULL | NULL | YES | FULLTEXT |  |  |
| tbl_job | 1 | job_title | 3 | job_additional_fields | NULL |    1 | NULL | NULL | YES | FULLTEXT |  |  |
+---------+---+-----------+---+-----------------------+------+------+------+------+-----+----------+--+--+

+----------+---+---------+---+---------+---+-----+------+------+--+-------+--+--+
| tbl_user | 0 | PRIMARY | 1 | user_id | A | 910 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |
+----------+---+---------+---+---------+---+-----+------+------+--+-------+--+--+

+---------------+---+---------+---+--------------+---+------+------+------+--+-------+--+--+
| tbl_workermap | 0 | PRIMARY | 1 | workermap_id | A | 7184 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |
+---------------+---+---------+---+--------------+---+------+------+------+--+-------+--+--+
```

EXPLAIN query

```
+---+--------+----------------+--------+---------+---------+------+-------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 1 | SIMPLE |      job       |  ALL   |  NULL   |  NULL   | NULL |             NULL              | 8283 |    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort    |
+---+--------+----------------+--------+---------+---------+------+-------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 1 | SIMPLE | estimategroup  | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4    | jobq.job.estimategroup_id     |    1 | Using where                                        |
| 1 | SIMPLE | brand          | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4    | jobq.job.brand_id             |    1 | Using index condition                              |
| 1 | SIMPLE | site           | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4    | jobq.job.site_id              |    1 | Using where                                        |
| 1 | SIMPLE | addedby        | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4    | jobq.job.addedby_user_id      |    1 | Using index condition                              |
| 1 | SIMPLE | requester      | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4    | jobq.job.requester_user_id    |    1 | Using index condition                              |
| 1 | SIMPLE | worker         | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4    | jobq.job.worker_user_id       |    1 | Using index condition                              |
| 1 | SIMPLE | status         | ALL    | PRIMARY | NULL    | NULL | NULL                          |    6 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
| 1 | SIMPLE | workermap      | ALL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | NULL                          | 7184 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
| 1 | SIMPLE | user_workermap | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4    | jobq.workermap.worker_user_id |    1 | Using where                                        |
| 1 | SIMPLE | categorymap    | ALL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | NULL                          |    1 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
| 1 | SIMPLE | category       | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4    | jobq.categorymap.category_id  |    1 | Using where                                        |
+---+--------+----------------+--------+---------+---------+------+-------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_job; and tbl_worker; and tbl_workermap; as well as  SHOW INDEX FROM tbl_job; and tbl_worker; and tbl_workermap; for analysis.   Also, post the EXPLAIN .... results, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I've added that info, thank you.

Comment: For the moment, you need two indexes to cover the basic rule of BOTH left and right objects of a JOIN = need an index. 1. ALTER TABLE tbl_workermap ADD INDEX idx_t_w_map_job_id (job_id) 2. ALTER TABLE tbl_workermap ADD INDEX idx_t_w_map_wrk_user_id (worker_user_id) after creation run EXPLAIN ..... to see new execution plan

Comment: @WilsonHauck Thank you, I've added those two indexes and that's done the trick, it's now near instant. If you can add that info as an answer I can mark it as accepted so you get the credit.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I'd be happy to do that, and have just done so :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jan 18, 2019 at 13:43 For the moment, you need two indexes to cover the basic rule of BOTH left and right objects of a JOIN = need an index. 1. ALTER TABLE tbl_workermap ADD INDEX idx_t_w_map_job_id (job_id) 2. ALTER TABLE tbl_workermap ADD INDEX idx_t_w_map_wrk_user_id (worker_user_id) after creation run EXPLAIN ..... to see new execution plan.

Comment: This solved the issue. I added indexes on tbl_workermap for `job_id` and `worker_user_id` and re-ran the EXPLAIN query. It no longer retrieves 7000+ rows from tbl_workermap and the query is now near instant. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have not already, create a clustered index by [setting a primary key](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp) (assuming the tables are properly normalized).  (If you haven't, you will likely want to [setup foreign key constraints](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) as well.)

**If this question were involved Microsoft SQL Server**, I would recommend creating a stored procedure, especially if this is a query run frequently as some sort of regular process. As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1157065/2109512), however, primary performance benefit for simple queries like this will be from table design and indices.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I am using primary keys, I've edited my post to show how these are set up.

Comment: @Adrian, it looks like you have a much more interesting problem than I had thought/hoped.

Regarding my stored procedure comment, I was mistaken. If you were using SQL Server, a stored procedure would probably save you some headaches, but it appears that is not the case with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

"A job can have one or more workers."  What about vice versa (a worker can be on multiple jobs)?  If not, then you have only 1:many, and you should not implement it with that extra table.

Assuming it really is many:many, there [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) are several tips on optimizing that table.

Don't use `LEFT` unless you are expecting the "right" table to be missing the desired row.

Style tip:  Get rid of `tbl_`, `user_` (except for `user_id`), etc.  That is prefixes on names are clutter and redundant with the context.  Be consistent on "user" versus "worker".

Have the many:many table named with both targets (eg, `worker_job`).  However, I now see that it is more than a simple many:many mapping table; it more like a table for assigning and tracking who is working on what *over time*?

If you need *both* a history of who worked on what *and* the current state of who is working on what, consider having two tables.  The history keeps growing; the 'current' keeps changing.

Use suitable datatypes, such as `DATE` and `DATETIME`.

Use InnoDB instead of MyISAM.

Comment: Thanks Rick, yes a worker can have multiple jobs so it is many:many. A job may have one, multiple or no workers assigned so there may or may not be an entry in tbl_workermap for any given job. I've edited my original post to clarify.

I'll have a read of that link now.

Comment: @Adrian - I made several added comments.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, the reason for both `user_id` and `worker_user_id` is that the users table contains both workers and other users. Someone assigning a job may not necessarily be a worker. I've solved the performance issue using WilsonHauck's advice above, but the two tables you suggest sounds like a good solution if this becomes an issue as the database size grows.